# Data table for doing sorting server side via ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

I can't seem to find a jquery data table for doing sorting via the server side.

I have total control of the data that is being returned, I return how many pages there are and the total amount per page.

I am trying to find some kind of data table so that i can show the number of pages, forward and backwards buttons and sortable column headers.

I dont want the jquery plugin to do all the work for me i just want to launch a jquery event so i can do a jquery ajax call and get the new page info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: http://www.datatables.net jquery plugin and implement the server side part and still have total control of the data being returned and also the sorting part.

CLIENT example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#members').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
            'bProcessing'    : true,
            'bServerSide'    : true,
            'sAjaxSource'    : 'example.com/sudo/get_list',
            "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
            'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
                aoData.push( { "name": "model", "value": "user" } );                
              $.ajax({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'     : sSource,
                'data'    : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback
              }); 
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                  {"bVisible": false},
                          { "sTitle": "Email" },
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"bVisible": false},
                          {"bVisible": false},                        
                          { "sTitle": "Type", "bSearchable": true },
                          { "sTitle": "State", "bSearchable": true },
                          { "sTitle": "Registered on", "bSearchable": true },
                          { "sTitle": "Last Login", "bSearchable": true },
                          null                                                
                        ]           
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Notice the: "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]]. Sorting by the 6th column(which for example would be member_id etc) but do not display it.

For the server side you could normally use your queries. Or you could use a native php library like this one: https://github.com/n1crack/IgnitedDatatables-native-php-version
In any case the server response using JSON format is similar to this:

```
sEcho
iTotalRecords
iTotalDisplayRecords
aaData
sColumns
```

each json key will be filled of course with your data.
Further info: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5133/ignited-datatables-native-php-version